# PHP TWIG date(H:i:s) from seconds

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am doing a project on symfony and I need to display time with format hours:minutes:seconds from a variable that holds only seconds.

Curretly I have this:  `$time_in_seconds|date('H:i:s')`

And the problem is that it always shows at least 01 hours... and I want it to show 00 if there is no hours present.

Even if I manually do `100|date('H:i:s')` it returns 01:01:40 instead of 00:01:40.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems it has something to do with timezones so when I specified +00:00 GMT it fixed it.

```
$time_in_seconds|date('H:i:s', '+00:00 GMT')
```

Comment: worked fine for me without the time zone. My data source is Oracle and using Symfony 5 with Twig. talktime|date('i:s')

Comment: It's not working when the total of seconds is over 24 hours. For example, with 172800 seconds (= 2 days) would display "00:00:00" instead of expected "48:00:00"

Comment: Seems like you can now add `false` to the timezones so the extra hour isn't added

Comment: What really happens when you pass `false` is that the timezone from the object you're reading is used. Its not just a -1 hour, but instead a adaption to the presented DateTimeZone.